# How to eagerload a list of entities?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

How would you eagerload all the relationship a particular entity has when you have a list of the entities such as:

```
List<Question> questions = query.getResultList();
```

Where the query is : `SELECT q FROM Question q;`

I know you can use `Hibernate.initialize()` but does that mean I need to loop through the list in the repostiory layer? Or are there a better solution?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [10.2.3.5.3. JPQL Fetch Joins](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_fetch_joins).

> A FETCH JOIN enables the fetching of an association as a side effect of the execution of a query. A FETCH JOIN is specified over an entity and its related entities.

An example borrowed from the link above:

```
SELECT mag FROM Magazine mag LEFT JOIN FETCH mag.articles WHERE mag.id = 1
```

I think an advantage of the `FETCH JOIN` is that your default setting can be lazy.